# Bing Maps Api: Deserialise Json result

Tags: c#, json.net, restsharp, bing-maps

I am using the Bing Maps Api to calculate the route between two points.
I use the Rest Services in combination with the RestSharp library.
Problem is that I don't know how I can access the Route results.

The results are of type Resource. Route derives of Resource.
The Resource class is decorated with the KnownType attribute.
FYI I use the JSON datacontracts from [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj870778.aspx)

Can someone help me?

Here is my code to calculate the route:

```
    public static double CalculateDistanceKm(string street, string postalCode, string city, string country)
    {
        var client = new RestClient(BingMapsApiUrl);
        var request = new RestRequest("Routes/Driving", Method.GET);
        request.AddParameter("wp.0", Address);
        request.AddParameter("wp.1", String.Format("{0},{1} {2},{3}", street, postalCode, city, country));
        request.AddParameter("ul", "50.7541313,4.2486601");
        request.AddParameter("key", BingMapsApiKey);

        var response = client.Execute(request);
        if (response.ResponseStatus == ResponseStatus.Completed)
        {
            var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Response>(response.Content);
            if (result != null && result.StatusCode == 200 & result.ResourceSets.Any() && result.ResourceSets[0].Resources.Any())
            {
                //How to get to the Route instead of just Resource...
                var test = result.ResourceSets.First().Resources.First();
            }
        }

        return 0;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I switched the api from Bing to Google Maps.
The api is a lot easier to use and it gave me the right results.

With Bing I had a 9/10 change to get a "Not_found" error, tested with the SAME address!
So sometimes it works (1/10 chance).
With Google I get a correct result on each try...

Don't make the same mistake as I did, if you want to lookup address in another language than english then use Google Maps API.

Comment: try the new Bing Maps v8, much better